# Copying in Java using streams - losing data/bytes

Tags: java, file, io, stream, copy

I have a problem with this method that is supposed to copy a file using streams:

```
public static void copyFile() {
    String[] paths = readSrcDestFromConsole(); //returns String array with two strings - source and destination file paths
    InputStream is = null; OutputStream os = null;
    File src = null; File dest = null;
    boolean error = false;
    long elapsedTimeSeconds = 0;
    double speed = 0;
    try {
        src = new File(paths[0]);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println("File read from could not be opened.");
        error = true;
    }
    if(!error) {
        try {
            dest = new File(paths[1]);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("File written to could not be created.");
            error = true;
        }
        if(src.exists() && !error) {
            if(dest.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File specified already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?");
                if(askForOverwrite()) { // gets Y or N from console using scanner and returns a boolean
                    try {
                        is = new FileInputStream(src);
                        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                        System.out.println("Copying from: " + paths[0] + " to: " + paths[1]);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        double read = 0;
                        long first = 0;
                        long second = 0;
                        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                        while(is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                            read += buffer.length;
                            os.write(buffer);
                            first = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
                            if(first != second) {
                                System.out.println(first + " % copied.");
                            }
                            second = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
                        }
                        elapsedTimeSeconds = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1_000_000_000;
                        speed = (src.length() / 1024 / 1024) / elapsedTimeSeconds;
                        is.close(); os.close();
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        System.err.println("File is or has been corrupted.");
                        error = true;
                    }finally{
                        if(!error) {
                            if(src.length() == dest.length()) {
                                System.out.println("File copied successfully.");
                                System.out.println("Total size copied: " + ((dest.length()) / 1024 / 1024) + " MB");
                                System.out.println("Copying speed: " + speed + " MB/s" + " in " + elapsedTimeSeconds + " seconds.");
                            }else{
                                System.err.println("Error: " + "File sizes mismatch.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("File has not been rewritten.");
                }
            }else{
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(src);
                    os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                    System.out.println("Copying from: " + paths[0] + " to: " + paths[1]);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    double read = 0;
                    long first = 0;
                    long second = 0;
                    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                    while(is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                        read += buffer.length;
                        os.write(buffer);
                        first = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
                        if(first != second) {
                            System.out.println(first + " % copied.");
                        }
                        second = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
                    }
                    elapsedTimeSeconds = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1_000_000_000;
                    speed = (src.length() / 1024 / 1024) / elapsedTimeSeconds;
                    is.close(); os.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.err.println("File is or has been corrupted.");
                    error = true;
                }finally{
                    if(!error) {
                        if(src.length() == dest.length()) {
                            System.out.println("File copied successfully.");
                            System.out.println("Total size copied: " + ((dest.length()) / 1024 / 1024) + " MB");
                            System.out.println("Copying speed: " + speed + " MB/s" + " in " + elapsedTimeSeconds + " seconds.");
                        }else{
                            System.err.println("Error: " + "File sizes mismatch.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.err.println("File specified does not exist.");
        }
    }else{
        System.err.println("Operation could not be completed.");
    }
}
```

Problem occurs when copying for example an image, a .txt file or sometimes video file, the error "File sizes mismatch." occurs. When I compare the source file and destination file sizes, the sizes really do mismatch, but images after opening seem to be complete, videos too. Visible problem is with text files - after copying and losing few bytes, none of the content is missing, but at the end of the file are few lines with some kind of marks saying "NUL" - using Notepad++ to view those.

I tried using the copy() method from Files, which works properly, but I can't find out why my method loses bytes.

Thank you very much for help, I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: 1) Eliminate duplicate code before it ruins your life. 2) `buffer.length` is always `4096` 3) you always write the full buffer, thus adding excessive bytes if you read less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read loop is the problem:

```
while(is.read(buffer) > 0) {
    read += buffer.length;
    os.write(buffer);
    first = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
    if(first != second) {
        System.out.println(first + " % copied.");
    }
    second = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
}
```

`is.read(buffer)` returns the number of bytes read. First of all, you have to check if it's greater than or equal to zero, because the contract of `read` allows it to read 0 bytes if the buffer is of size zero. But beyond that - you need to keep that value around because you have to write only the number of bytes you read.

Usually, the size of the file is not exactly a multiple of 4096. Thus, the last read will read fewer than 4096 bytes. And the `read` contract actually says that it can read less than 4096 even before that if fewer bytes are available at the time.

So if you don't write exactly what you have read, a part of the buffer that you write will contain values from the previous read, or zeros if the file is smaller than 4096 bytes.

So correct it to:

```
int numRead;

while( (numRead = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    read += numRead;
    os.write(buffer,0,numRead);
    first = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
    if(first != second) {
        System.out.println(first + " % copied.");
    }
    second = Math.round(read / src.length() * 100);
}
```

But indeed, it's recommended to use the `Files` class whenever your copy involves at least one file, and to avoid `java.io.File` in favor of `Path`, with operations available in `Paths` and `Files`.

Comment: @JamesKPolk OK, I corrected the condition when 0 is allowed. In any case, end of file arrives only with `-1`, not with `0`.